# How can I avoid a delay after logged in facebook successfully?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

Here is my code to redirect HomeActivity after logged in facebook successfully, but it has a delay. Who can show me the way to avoid it or show the ProgressDialog instead of the delay. Thanks for your helps.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Log.e("login", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Log.e("login", "error");
        }
    });
```